# Why Update_column() fails when called during before_update() in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to use update_column() during a callback before_save and/or before_update. But it fails to update it during the callback.
An author has many books, at a time only one book can be active. Book has only one author in reverse.

Here I am trying to deactivate the activated book and activating the one for which book quantity changed(when book quantity is updated for a stock)

Below is the code.

```
class Books
before_update :check_book_quantity

private
 def check_book_quantity
   if self.quantity_changed? && !self.active
     books_in_stock = Author.where(book_id: self.id, active: true)
     books_in_stock.first.update_column(:active, false)
     self.active = true
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: In short, how can i another object during active record callback?

Comment: what is the error ocurring? also have you tried to use update_column(active: false) ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried that only.  (self.active = true), executes successfully but books_in_stock.first.update_column(:active, false) is not getting executed @GabrielMesquita

Comment: Have you used a byebug to be sure that your if clause is correct and the execution flow gets to the update_column call?

Comment: Yes, I am using it . Its going inside if clause.

Comment: could you try to use this books_in_stock.first.update_attribute(:active, false),  does it work?

Comment: Nope, its calling the callbacks and making it an infinite loop.

Comment: makes sense haha, do you need to be before_update? could it be before_save?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
class Books
before_update :check_book_quantity, :if => :quantity_changed?

private
 def check_book_quantity
   unless self.active
     books_in_stock = Author.where(book_id: self.id, active: true)
     books_in_stock.first.update_attribute(:active, false)
   end
 end
end
```

You can pass the `quantity_changed?` verification to the callback declaration. This way, you won't have this loop. You can refactor the `!self.active` and use `unless`. Also you can use update_attribute instead of update_column.

Hope it helped!

Comment: I first checked with this. it did not work for me so I changed my code to the one which I mentioned here. @Gabriel mesquita

Comment: There is no such error but the record is not getting updated. @gabriel mesquita

Comment: is books_in_stock returning something?  In my code, can you use byebug to verify if the update is being correctly called?

Comment: As we are calling it before_save , so the value is getting assigned to books_in_stock but if you check the same after the update it changes to true again which is not expected

Comment: Is there a before_save?